# CSS. Remove space between list items

Tags: html, css, web, css-selectors

**What I have :**

[image]

As you see there's little space between home and blog, how do I remove it through CSS?

**my code:**

```
#wrapper{
    width:80%;
    background: coral;
    margin:0 auto;
}

ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul>li{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:100px;
}

ul>li>a{
    display: block;
    padding:20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

I don't want to place the list items on the same line in html.

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/g79bLzmd/

Comment: @ketan why does a "comment" make that ?